# CGAL loop over facets sharing an edge

Tags: c++, cgal

Hello fellow Stackers,

I would like to write a function that loops over all finite edges of a CGAL regular 3D triangulation, and calculates the angles between all pairs of faces (facets) sharing that edge. In the reference guide I found a method called  [incident_facets](http://doc.cgal.org/latest/TDS_3/classTriangulationDataStructure__3.html#a5fa05dff151b3248d8a94d5634fb671d) that should give the circulator to all facets incident to a specific edge. I'm not 100% certain that that is the method I'm looking for, but most of all, I have no idea how to use it. Could anyone perhaps show me how it works in practice? Also, does anyone know if there already is a built-in CGAL method that loops over all finite facet pairs, so I don't have to write it out explicitly?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

no, there no built-in CGAL method that loops over all finite facet pairs.

You can find an example for the use of a circulator there
http://doc.cgal.org/latest/Triangulation_2/index.html#title9

In your case, it could be easier to iterate on all finite cells and look at the 6 pairs of facets in each tetrahedron.

best,